# Wordpress theme layout

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress theme.  I have a site, and I am trying to make it similar to (this site)[http://www.airbnb.com/].  Can anyone help me, or direct me to a similar theme that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: kindly remove .Can from end in url

Comment: i have downloaded a free wordpress theme and working on it.but my specific need is user should find there place and book a room for their self as i am making hotel booking site.As given in http://www.airbnb.com/

Comment: It seems that you need to know or your question should be "how to implement an online hotel room booking site using WordPress" and this is not only WordPress theme related issue and this is not possible to get it done here.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve an online booking system by Integrating the [Rezgo, the leading tour and activity booking platform](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rezgo-online-booking/) with your WordPress regular theme. this Plugin is FREE :)

this is a screenshot of what the booking plugin looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.org](https://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rezgo-online-booking/screenshot-4.png?r=677712))</sub>

or you could download a nice clean responsive hotel Accommodation theme. Click the image below:

[image]

another theme is

[image]

the choice is yours... visit [Themeforest](https://themeforest.net/) and search for hotel themes... i bet you'll find many

Hope this Points you to the right path... Goodluck!